# Выпадает по нехватке памяти

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Выпадает с ошибкой

> Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x779F3E28 в CourseProject.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::bad_alloc по адресу памяти 0x001DE598.

Выпадает на строке:

```
PP[i + 1] = tmp;
```

Вот по полный код сортировки.

```
void sort(Plane* PP, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        PP[i].fuel_on_one_passangers();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (PP[i + 1].price < PP[i].price)
        {
            Plane tmp = PP[i];
            PP[i] = PP[i + 1];
            PP[i + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот [здесь](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KS3K/nKvm6W6eW) полный код проекта

Comment: У вас цикл до count, элементы нумеруются с нуля. i+1 просто выходит за пределы массива

Comment: когда `i==count-1` - последний элемент, то `i+1` - за границами массива

Comment: @Abyx, почему? можете аргументировать?

Comment: @Abyx, как по мне, то писать велосипеды при изучении базовых вещей вполне обычное дело. Человеку ведь нужно не сэкономить время на написание кода (и увеличение скорости выполнения программы ...) а научиться программировать.

Comment: я вот не могу додуматься, как мне сделать так что бы я не выходил за границы массива

Comment: @taruuuch, у вас как минимум какай-то странная сортировка, скорее мне кажется что она не сработает правильно. Но чтобы не выходить за границы почему бы не поставить условие выхода `i < count - 1;` ?

Answer (score 5):

Функция имеет неопределенное поведение, потому что в ней имеет место попытка обратиться к памяти за пределами массива

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (PP[i + 1].price < PP[i].price)
        ^^^^^^^^^  
    {
        Plane tmp = PP[i];
        PP[i] = PP[i + 1];
                ^^^^^^^^^
        PP[i + 1] = tmp;
        ^^^^^^^^^ 
    }
}
```

Если массив имеет count элементов, то при `i` равном `count-1` выражение `PP[i + 1]` пытается разыменовать несуществующий элемент с индексом `count`, так как допустимый диапазон индексов `[0, count - 1]`

Также имейте в виду, что ваша функция ничего не сортирует. Она лишь элемент массива с максимальным значением поля `price` перемещает на самую крайнюю позицию массива.